# how to pass document type parameter to xslt using saxon

Tags: xslt, saxon

I want to use saxon to transform xml

**and in the XSLT** ,

i add a parameter which i expect it as a "Document"

```
<xsl:param name="doc" as="node()*" />
```

**and in java** ,

```
    DOM4JDocumentWrapper documentNode = new DOM4JDocumentWrapper(doc4j, "", config);
    NodeInfo nodeInfo=documentNode.getRoot();
    XsltTransformer tr =   xsltExecutable.load();
    tr.setParameter(idQname, new XdmNode(nodeInfo));
```

**but met such error:**

```
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot convert value class net.sf.saxon.option.dom4j.DOM4JNodeWrapper of type element(Q{}xxx) to class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyElementImpl
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.PJConverter$Identity.convert(PJConverter.java:527)
```

Comment: What are `xsltExecutable` and `XdmNode`? Links to docs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be as if the Saxon Configuration you are using is not aware of the DOM4J object model implementation. That is, it has not been registered using Configuration.registerExternalObjectModel().

With Saxon-PE and Saxon-EE this should be known by default, but with Saxon-HE it has to be registered explicitly. So we need to know more about what version of the Saxon software you are using and how it is initialized.

This question is very specific to Saxon, and the best strategy for getting answers to such questions is to ask on the forums at saxonica.plan.io. We check questions tagged "saxon" on StackOverflow from time to time, but it can take a few days before we notice them, and we don't give them priority.

Comment: I have also some functions which returns a dom4j document. Now I want to run xPath expression on it. There for I want to use the saxon9he.jar library. So I downloaded [saxon9-dom4j.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsaxon9dom4jjar.htm) and want to initialize a object `DocumentWrapper documentNode = new DocumentWrapper(doc4j,"",config);`. But I dont know how to create a valid config Object.

Comment: To create a config I tried `Processor proc = new Processor(false);
   Configuration configuration = proc.getUnderlyingConfiguration();
   configuration.registerExternalObjectModel(new DOM4JObjectModel());` But that throws the error _The type net.sf.saxon.om.ExternalObjectModel cannot be resolved_ . I checked my saxon9he.jar and I could not find ExternalObjectModel.class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think we support use of external object models in Saxon-HE. It can probably be made to work because the code is all open source, but you're on your own doing the integration.

Comment: So if I want to compile any xPath expression on a dom4j document with saxon9he I have to convert it to dom, jdom2 or xml?

Comment: You've got a number of choices: you can pay £50 for a Saxon-PE license, you can pay rather more than that for consultancy, you can work out how to do it yourself, or you can hope that someone will work it out for you and not charge you. (Sorry to be commercial about it. Remember that with a lot of open source software the business model is to give the software away free and charge for support and advice.)

Comment: Ok, is there a tutorial how build saxon9he for java from source? I compile and package the [latest 9.7](https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/) via maven. But if I try to use this jar I got a NullPointer exception.

Comment: Your link to the "latest 9.7" is to the SVN repository. You will probably find it easier to use the source code archive on SourceForge as your starting point: https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.7/saxon9-7-0-4source.zip/download - that's because the SVN version includes preprocessor directives allowing source to be generated for different environments.